Prove that for events $A$, $B$ such that: $\mathbb{P}(B) > 0$, it's true that: $\mathbb{P}(A|A \cup B) ≥ \mathbb{P}(A|B)$
Prove that for events $A$, $B$ such that: $\mathbb{P}(B) > 0$, it's true that: $\mathbb{P}(A|A \cup B) ≥ \mathbb{P}(A|B)$.
I tried to do the following:
$$\mathbb{P}(A|A \cup B) ≥ \mathbb{P}(A|B)$$
$$\frac{\mathbb{P} (A \cap (A \cup B))}{\mathbb{P}(A \cup B)} ≥ \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$$
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) + \mathbb{P}(B)} ≥ \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(A) \mathbb{P}(B) \geq \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) + \mathbb{P}(A \cap B)\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) + \mathbb{P}(B)\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$$
Or alternatively:
$$\mathbb{P}(A) \mathbb{P}(B) \geq \mathbb{P}(A \cap B)\mathbb{P}(A \cup B)$$
Eather way, I don't see why that would be the case

$\mathbb P(A \cup B) = \mathbb P(A) - \mathbb P(A \cap B) + \mathbb P(B)$, not $+$.

You might argue $f(x)=\frac{c+x}{d+x}$ has derivative $f'(x)=\frac{d-c}{(d+x)^2}$ which is non-negative when $d\ge c$

Let $a = \mathbb{P}(A \cap B), b = \mathbb{P}(A - B), c = \mathbb{P}(B - A)$. We have
$$\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B) = (a + b)(a + c),$$
$$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\mathbb{P}(A\cup B) = a(a + b + c),$$
and
$$(a + b)(a + c) - a(a + b + c) = bc \geq 0.$$

Why not have a proof without word

$\mathbb{P}[A|B]=\dfrac{\text{green}}{\text{blue}+\text{green}}$
$\mathbb{P}[A|A\cup B]=\dfrac{\text{Yellow}+\text{Green}}{\text{Yellow}+\text{blue}+\text{green}}$
Which one is larger?
